# How to give legend to such a plot

Tags: plotting, legending

The [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) is as given on the *Mathematica* website

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 3}]
 , {x, 0, 15}
 , PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thick}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 3}], {x, 0, 15}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thick},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 3}]
 , {x, 0, 15}
 , PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thick}
 , PlotLegends -> Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 3}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

<sub>Code and plots done in *Mathemathica 11.1.1* on Win7</sub>